# R: Generating random contrasting colors

Tags: r

I would like to create an alternating color palette. For example, the first element of the vector/color palette would be dark brown, the next light red, the next dark green, the next light yellow, and etc.

I am trying to use `hcl` and this is what I have right now. Maybe I should use colorbrewer?

```
x <- 5
hcl(h=seq(15,375,length=(x+1)),l=65,c=100)[1:x]

# [1] "#F8766D" "#D89000" "#A3A500" "#39B600" "#00BF7D"
```

Desired:

```
# [1] "#7A007A" "#EB9999" "#5C993D" "#85A3FF" "#000000"
# #    DARKPINK  LIGHTRED DARKGREEN LIGHTBLUE   BLACK
# #    Something like this, you get the idea
```

IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:

I will be using the colors like this with geom_raster. As you can see, it is sometimes difficult to distinguish between juxtaposed tiles.
[image]

Comment: RColorBrewer provides a few palettes with contrasting pastel colors.

Comment: I need a way to generate them because the value of x is variable, and therefore may be extremely large.

Comment: If you will be presenting more than ~10 colors, this visualization will probably be lost. Hard to say because you don't say what will be the usage.

Comment: Please see my edit @RomanLuštrik